# Can I use a visa which I obtained for a conference and which didn't use it for a vist now to Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, change-purpose-of-travel

I obtained visa to Canada for a conference in May. But I couldn't go. Got visa as B1 visitor-business multiple. Now I got an invitation from a relative in Canada to visit them. Can I use the earlier Visa which I didn't use for this?

Comment: Did you contact the Embassy that issued it? What did they say?

Comment: Dear RodneyThanks for the concern.Im going there tomorrow.